Why passing a variable in \pstScalePoints(0.00111111,0.03){\dateDebut sub}{ 100 sub } doesn't work?
Can someone tell me why it doesn't work when I try to pass a variable into \pstScalePoints ?
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data1}
1679117400 112.46
1679118300 112.42
1679119200 217.70
1679120100 217.70
1679121000 217.70
1679121900 217.70
1679122800 228.70
1679123700 228.70
1679124600 227.70
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{param}
16
8
450
1679117400
1679124600
0:00:00,0:00:02,0:00:04,0:00:06,0:00:08,0:00:10,0:00:12,0:00:14,0:00:16
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{readarray}

%chargement des paramètres
\readarraysepchar{\\}
\readdef{param}\myrawdata %param est le nom du fichier avec les
                          %paramètres 
\setsepchar{\\/,}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\readlist*{\mydata}{\myrawdata}

%assignation des paramètres
\def\largeur{\mydata[1,1]}
\def\hauteur{\mydata[2,1]}
\def\Dx{\mydata[3,1]}
\def\dateDebut{\mydata[4,1]}
\def\labelXa{\mydata[6,1]}
\def\labelXb{\mydata[6,2]}
\def\labelXc{\mydata[6,3]}
\def\labelXd{\mydata[6,4]}
\def\labelXe{\mydata[6,5]}
\def\labelXf{\mydata[6,6]}
\def\labelXg{\mydata[6,7]}
\def\labelXh{\mydata[6,8]}
\def\labelXi{\mydata[6,9]}

\makeatletter
\edef\psk@xLabels{\labelXa,\labelXb,\labelXc,\labelXd,\labelXe,\labelXf,\labelXg,\labelXh,\labelXi} 
\makeatother

\readdata{\data}{data1}

\psset{xAxisLabel=,yAxisLabel=,
llx=-5mm,urx=1cm,lly=-5mm,
mathLabel=false,xlabelsep=-5pt,
axesstyle=frame,xticksize=0 7.59,yticksize=0
25,subticks=0} 

\pstScalePoints(0.00111111,0.03){\dateDebut sub}{ 100 sub } %1679117400
\psgraph[labels=y,Dx=1,dx=1,Dy=10,dy=0.3,Oy=100]{->}(0,0)(8,4){16cm}{8cm}
  \listplot[showpoints,dotstyle=triangle,linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt]{\data}
\endpsgraph

\dateDebut
\end{document}

And this works :
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data1}
1679117400 112.46
1679118300 112.42
1679119200 217.70
1679120100 217.70
1679121000 217.70
1679121900 217.70
1679122800 228.70
1679123700 228.70
1679124600 227.70
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{param}
16
8
450
1679117400
1679124600
0:00:00,0:00:02,0:00:04,0:00:06,0:00:08,0:00:10,0:00:12,0:00:14,0:00:16
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{readarray}

%chargement des paramètres
\readarraysepchar{\\}
\readdef{param}\myrawdata %param est le nom du fichier avec les
                          %paramètres 
\setsepchar{\\/,}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\readlist*{\mydata}{\myrawdata}

%assignation des paramètres
\def\largeur{\mydata[1,1]}
\def\hauteur{\mydata[2,1]}
\def\Dx{\mydata[3,1]}
\def\dateDebut{\mydata[4,1]}
\def\labelXa{\mydata[6,1]}
\def\labelXb{\mydata[6,2]}
\def\labelXc{\mydata[6,3]}
\def\labelXd{\mydata[6,4]}
\def\labelXe{\mydata[6,5]}
\def\labelXf{\mydata[6,6]}
\def\labelXg{\mydata[6,7]}
\def\labelXh{\mydata[6,8]}
\def\labelXi{\mydata[6,9]}

\makeatletter
\edef\psk@xLabels{\labelXa,\labelXb,\labelXc,\labelXd,\labelXe,\labelXf,\labelXg,\labelXh,\labelXi} 
\makeatother

\readdata{\data}{data1}

\psset{xAxisLabel=,yAxisLabel=,
llx=-5mm,urx=1cm,lly=-5mm,
mathLabel=false,xlabelsep=-5pt,
axesstyle=frame,xticksize=0 7.59,yticksize=0
25,subticks=0} 

\pstScalePoints(0.00111111,0.03){1679117400 sub}{ 100 sub } %1679117400
\psgraph[labels=y,Dx=1,dx=1,Dy=10,dy=0.3,Oy=100]{->}(0,0)(8,4){16cm}{8cm}
  \listplot[showpoints,dotstyle=triangle,linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt]{\data}
\endpsgraph

\dateDebut

\end{document}

Thank you for your help !

I retagged to pstricks as there is no latex3 code here.

You are generating an argument 1679117400sub but need 1679117400 sub so use \dateDebut\space sub

Thank you ! it works

or use \def\dateDebut{\mydata[4,1] }.  (A space after ] )
